# How to delete all files saved in DDMS data in android?

Tags: android, file, delete-file, ddms

I have saved some ser file by below code

```
OutputStream file = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


            BufferedOutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream( file );

            ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);

            try{

              output.writeObject(map1);



            }
```

Now please tell me how to delete all files saved through this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this,
Get the Path of folder that you want to delete with all files and then delete all files one by one.

```
File dir = new File("/data/directory_name/");

if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is generally for every directory.

Comment: But how to get the path of DDMS data directory?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/filenameWithExtenstion");
file.delete();
```

Comment: This code is to delete a single file. I want to delete all files saved there. Please provide me the code for this. Thanks.

Comment: You want to delete all files inside data folder?

Comment: To get the list of files from the Directory use the `file.list()` method